# TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. Problems with successfully removing objects

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, removechild, addchild, array-splice

I am trying to make a game involving a dragon burning little knights, fairly simple but I am new to AS3 and can't seem to solve this problem, sometimes when I kill a knight it returns an output error saying:
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at drogtor/onTick()

I can't find any relevant solutions elsewhere on this website so I am submitting a question myself.

Here is (what I think to be) the relevant code.

```
package  
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import global;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;


public class drogtor extends MovieClip 
{
    private var updown:Boolean=true;
    private var fArray:Array;
    private var eArray:Array;
    var wpressed:Boolean = false;
    var apressed:Boolean = false;
    var dpressed:Boolean = false;
    var spressed:Boolean = false;
    var kspawn:Number = 5;
    public function drogtor() 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onTick);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fliy);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fliy);
        fArray = new Array();
        eArray = new Array();
    }
    public function onTick(e:Event):void
    {
        var fcount:int=0;
        var sdargon:int=10;
        var rdargon:int=6;
        var Angle:Number = (2 * Math.PI * (dargon.rotation/360));
        var dy:Number = sdargon * Math.cos(Angle);
        var dx:Number = sdargon * Math.sin(Angle);
        HitBox.x = dargon.x;
        HitBox.y = dargon.y;
        HitBox.rotation = dargon.rotation;


        //Flame Spewer
        if (global.count==9)
        {
            var fAngle:Number = (2 * Math.PI * (dargon.rotation/360));
            var fdy:Number = 10 * Math.cos(fAngle);
            var fdx:Number = 10 * Math.sin(fAngle);
            var ftemp:Flame=new Flame;
            ftemp.x=dargon.x + (10 * fdx);
            ftemp.y=dargon.y - (10 * fdy);
            ftemp.rotation=dargon.rotation + Math.random() * (15-(-15)) + (-15);
            fArray.push(ftemp);
            addChildAt(ftemp, 0);
        }
        var kgen:int = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3)+1);
        var stageside:int = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4)+1)
        if (kgen == 1)
        {
            if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) <= kspawn)
            {
                var ktemp:keniget = new keniget;
                if (stageside == 1)
                {
                    ktemp.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    ktemp.y = 0
                }
                else if (stageside == 2)
                {
                    ktemp.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    ktemp.y = stage.stageHeight;
                }
                else if (stageside == 3)
                {
                    ktemp.x = 0;
                    ktemp.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                }
                else if (stageside == 4)
                {
                    ktemp.x = stage.stageWidth;
                    ktemp.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                }
                eArray.push(ktemp);
                addChildAt(ktemp, 0);
            }
        }
        for (var iKl:int = eArray.length-1; iKl >= 0; iKl --)
        {
            var krotation:Number = (Math.atan2(eArray[iKl].y-dargon.y, eArray[iKl].x-dargon.x) * 180/Math.PI) - 90;
            eArray[iKl].rotation = krotation
            var kangle:Number = (2 * Math.PI * (eArray[iKl].rotation/360));
            var edx:Number = 3 * Math.sin(kangle);
            var edy:Number = 3 * Math.cos(kangle);
            eArray[iKl].x += edx;
            eArray[iKl].y -= edy;
            if (eArray[iKl].hitTestObject(HitBox))
            {
                removeChild(eArray[iKl]);
                eArray.splice(iKl, 1);
            }
            for (var iF:int=fArray.length-1; iF>=0; iF--)
            {
                if (eArray[iKl].hitTestObject(fArray[iF]))
                {
                    removeChild(eArray[iKl]);
                    eArray.splice(iKl, 1);
                    kspawn += 0.5
                }
            }
        }





        for(var iFl:int=fArray.length-1; iFl>=0; iFl--)
        {
            if(fArray[iFl].currentFrame==fArray[iFl].totalFrames)
            {
                removeChild(fArray[iFl]);
                fArray[iFl]=null;
                fArray.splice(iFl, 1);
            }
        }
        if(updown)
        {
            dargon.rotationX-=1;
            if(dargon.rotationX == -10)
            {
                updown = false;
            }
        }
        if(!updown)
        {
            dargon.rotationX+=1;
            if(dargon.rotationX == 10)
            {
                updown = true;
            }
        }
        //Movement
        if(wpressed)
        {
            dargon.x += dx;
            dargon.y -= dy;
        }
        if(apressed)
        {
            dargon.rotation -= rdargon;
        }
        if(dpressed)
        {
            dargon.rotation += rdargon;
        }
        if(spressed)
        {
            dargon.x -= ((1/4) * dx);
            dargon.y += ((1/4) * dy)
        }
    }
    public function fliy(ke:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if(ke.type == "keyDown")
        {
            //key=A
            if(ke.keyCode==87)
            {
                wpressed=true;
            }
            //Key=A
            if(ke.keyCode==65)
            {
                apressed=true;
            }
            //Key=D
            if(ke.keyCode==68)
            {
                dpressed=true;
            }
            if(ke.keyCode==83)
            {
                spressed=true;
            }
        }
        if(ke.type == "keyUp")
        {
            //key=A
            if(ke.keyCode==87)
            {
                wpressed=false;
            }
            //Key=A
            if(ke.keyCode==65)
            {
                apressed=false;
            }
            //Key=D
            if(ke.keyCode==68)
            {
                dpressed=false;
            }
            if(ke.keyCode==83)
            {
                spressed=false;
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that even though you removed the knight from the display list, the code is still running in the onTick function, and you are trying to access something that is not existing, I suggest you to check whether your knight's reference is null or not, if not, then run the code, else skip it.
**EDIT:**
Whenever you null an instance (`myInstance = null`), you can no longer access to it's properties, functions etc.. and if you try, then you get that error above. To avoid it, check whether your object is null or not.

```
if(myInstance != null) {
    //do your stuff with your instance
}
```

Comment: Sorry new to AS3, but how exactly would I check if the knight's reference is null?